# What are popular songs with a philharmonic orchestra arrangement/accompaniment called?

Tags: terminology, orchestra, arranging

I am trying to understand whether there is a name for this genre,
For example, [Somewhere over the rainbow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSZxmZmBfnU) and many songs of Ray Charles [like this Eleanor Rigby one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-wiHI-GkSU) and like in this [Barbra Streisand concert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS_jdJyJRcU) and even this [Scorpions - Still Loving You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_p51VxgHJM)

I'm not talking about a song performed solely by an orchestra but rather a song which is sung by a lead singer and accompanied by an orchestra in sort of like a film orchastration style but not related to films (Somewhere over the rainbow is an exception).

Eventually I hope I could find a playlist of songs in this genre so I could study this orchastration style further.

Comment: …& in the week we lost Gary Brooker, it would seem an appropriate time to listen to [Procol Harum, Conquistador - Live with the Edmonton Symphony Orchestra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPlf09nVgWk)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a misperception: Including an orchestra or strings doesn't constitute a genre, and many different genres use them (Metallica and Sting both give concerts with symphony orchestras).

Comment: In the beginning I was also thinking there is no such genre but as I look more into it I find so many songs that were made this way and no other way, I think it should've had a genre name. another example: Frank Sinatra - It Was A Very Good Year https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TeDfgUvyKHk

Answer (score 4):

There's no special term for these kinds of arrangements, but a Google search for "[pop songs with orchestra](https://www.google.com/search?q=pop%20songs%20with%20orchestra&oq=pop%20songs%20with%20orchestra)" and a YouTube search for "[pop songs with orchestral backing](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=pop%20songs%20with%20orchestral%20backing)" both gave lots of results. The YouTube search must be popular, because the terms came up well before I finished typing.